# Issues Regarding Data Model Abstraction in Golang

Tags: design, web-development, mvc, sql, go

I am currently writing a quiz web-app with a React front-end and a Golang backend, with a PostgreSQL database to keep track of the quizzes, the questions on the quizzes, and the choices in the questions.

My approach currently involves having `Quiz`, `Question`, and `Choice` structs, where I've abstracted the SQL away into functions such as `GetQuizzes()` (which just does a `SELECT * FROM quiz`), `(q *Quiz) AddQuestion(/*question data*/)`, and other things that would help common actions on my website.

On the frontend, I will most likely not be needing every field from a table each time I display data related to that table, and while I could pare down the structs in my handlers, only sending the data needed for that view, it seems wasteful to be grabbing every field when I `GetQuizByID` or what have you. I know I could write the `SQL` directly in my handlers, which would allow me to have complete control over my data where I could even do things like `JOIN` (which does not make *any* sense in my current architecture, which seems like a bad sign). However, this would abandon the whole MVC pattern that I am trying to practice/think about.

My quetion is whether I should continue with this and just take my lumps grabbing every field and having little control over what I load and what I don't, versus abandoning this model layer and just using SQL wherever I please. Obviously, this app isn't super reliant on having state-of-the-art performance, but my goal is to use my knowledge here to apply to more *real* circumstances that I might run into later on in my career.

Disclaimer: I am pretty new to this web-programming stuff (especially backend), so let me know if I'm totally off base and need to hit the books again.